# best way to sum up Matrix elements parallel in c#

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

What is the fastest most efficient way to sumUp all matrix elements parallel in .net 4.0 ?

using Parallel.For end in inner loop making lock(objectLock) { result += matrix[i, j] } is 2 times slowwer then sequential approach.

thanks for any hints,
bye

Comment: `lock` effectively blocks your code to synchronize it, so the slowdown should be expected.

Answer (score 2):

[`ParallelEnumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.sum.aspx) knows how to do the sum without needing either locking or interlocked operations (I assume it sums subsets on each thread, and then sums those results).

Assuming your matrix is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<numeric>>`:

```
var sum = (from row in matrix.AsParallel()
           select row.Sum()).Sum();
```

The [`AsParallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413237.aspx) means the rows are processed in parallel, but the inner (column) sum is just [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) (unless the rows are very long, the overhead of concurrency will overwhelm any possible benefits).

Comment: Edit your answer: `select (row.Sum()).Sum();` to `select row.Sum()).Sum();`

Answer (score 1):

Well you can consider your martrix[m,n] to m arrays whose length is n and then sum the m arrays parallelly. And by the way, you shouldn't use `lock` here, use `Interlocked.Add` instead. I'm busy now, I'll write an example if I have time then.

Answer (score -1):

Use static variables for i,j and result without using lock

Comment: You can't modify result with non atomic operations from multiple threads and expect the correct result. Each thread needs it's own accumulator and then add all accumulators using a single thread.